# Determining the minimal bounding surface around a magnet at which another magnet will not be attracted to it

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, measurements, simulations

I have two cylindrical bar magnets, $1/4" \mathrm{(\sim 6mm)}$ in length and diameter.

Like all magnets with this geometry they attract each other both on the axial direction-north pole of one attracted to the south pole of the other and along their radial direction-south pole of one facing up, the north pole of the other facing up (stuck to each other sideways)

I am interested to know what is the minimal confining shape around the magnet (in 3d), so that when the magnet is embedded in it, the magnets will "feel" equal force of attraction along the whole shell of that surface to another magnet.

The final outcome I am hoping to achieve is to embed both magnets in the minimum plastic case of a specific shape, so that the magnets "do not attract" each other (at least not in a meaningful way. if we need a number we can use $0.5\mathrm{N}$ of force required to separate the magnets in the direction normal to the bounding surface).

My physics is a little rusty and I would greatly appreciate some guidance on how to approach this problem, and possibly a solution (simulation or other). thanks

Comment: Do you have any information regarding the strength of the magnets?  For example, neodymium magnets that you can order over the internet have designations such as N45.

Comment: Thanks David for the clarification. These are Neodymium magnets. I don’t know the grade of what I have, but we can assume N45 and pull force of 4lb.  I am mostly interested in the general solution (size and grade might change a little) and how to best approach this problem and derive the bounding surface, so we can probably treat all the measurements as variables for the general solution.

Comment: You may be able to research magnet strengths, find out how much weight each magnet can pick up, and identify the specs for your magnets.  Good luck.